# 'int' object is not iterable while creating dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, random

I'm trying to create a dictionary in python. However, I want to create the dictionary using the random values. The desired output should be in the form {'a':1, 'b':2} in the format.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
import string

value = np.random.random(10)
np.random.seed(42)
key = list(np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), 10))
key, value

def map_values(key, value):
    i = len(key)
    j = len(value)
    for i in len(key):
        print('key[i]' +'value[j]')
        i = i+1
        j = j+1
    return map_values()

map_values(key, value)
```

However while running the above code, I got the error 'int' object is not iterable. Can someone explain the reason for the error and rectify the code as I'm new to python and trying to learn it.

Comment: `for i in len(key):` should be `for i in range(len(key)):` or `xrange(len(key))` if you are in python 2.

Comment: in `for i in len(key):`, `len(key)` returns an `int` and you try to iterate over that using the for loop, hence the error.

Comment: Can you specify the rectified code for the desired output?

Answer (score 2):

There are several errors with your code:

1. You need to iterate over `range(len(key))`, not the integer `len(key)`.
2. You have not initialized any dictionary, or attempted to update a dictionary.
3. Your function returns `map_values()`, but a recursive algorithm is not required.
4. You assign variables to the lengths of `key` and `value` arrays, but then reassign them in your for loop.
5. You do not use indices to extract elements from your `key` and `value` arrays.

As such, you can just use `dict` + `zip`:

```
np.random.seed(42)

key = np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), 10)
value = np.random.random(10)

res = dict(zip(key, value))

{'g': 0.83244264080042174,
 'h': 0.020584494295802447,
 'k': 0.70807257779604549,
 'o': 0.6011150117432088,
 's': 0.18182496720710062,
 't': 0.86617614577493518,
 'u': 0.96990985216199432,
 'w': 0.18340450985343382,
 'z': 0.21233911067827616}
```